# How to display version in Mlflow UI in column

Tags: mlflow

I have developed multiple modeling in mlflow where in I would like to create model versioning so that the version of that model can be track down for the easy identification based on the timestamp.

Kindly provide the documentation specific to model versioning.

Comment: You can log version manually using `mlflow.log_param()`, it will be shown in a new column in mlflow ui.

Comment: Please don't copy-paste the same text into your question several times

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a [Model Registry](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html)
There you can track versions of the model and make different stages